# How to use LIKE and IN operators in one query?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-like

My simple sql statement is this:

```
SELECT USERNAME FROM ALL_USERS;
```

But I want to filter system users from the result. I searched but couldn't find anything  that Oracle provided; so I tried a statement like this and it doesn't work:

```
select username from all_users where username not like '%SH%' 
    or username not like '%SYS%' 
    or username not in ('ANONYMOUS',            
                        'DBSNMP',
                        'MGMT_VIEW',
                        'ORDPLUGINS',
                        'OUTLN',
                        'SI_INFORMATION_SCHEMA',
                        'WK_TEST',
                        'WKPROXY',
                        'XDB');
```

This doesn't work. How should I modify my query for the desired output or maybe there is something oracle provides to get predefined system accounts?

Answer (score 5):

A slight twist on the other answers: not (A or B or C) = not A and not B and not C, so what you probably originally wanted was:

```
select username from all_users 
where not (username like '%SH%' 
           or username like '%SYS%' 
           or username in ('ANONYMOUS',            
                        'DBSNMP',
                        'MGMT_VIEW',
                        'ORDPLUGINS',
                        'OUTLN',
                        'SI_INFORMATION_SCHEMA',
                        'WK_TEST',
                        'WKPROXY',
                        'XDB')
           );
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `OR`, you will need to use `AND`

```
select username from all_users where username not like '%SH%' 
  AND username not like '%SYS%' 
  AND username not in ('ANONYMOUS',            
                    'DBSNMP',
                    'MGMT_VIEW',
                    'ORDPLUGINS',
                    'OUTLN',
                    'SI_INFORMATION_SCHEMA',
                    'WK_TEST',
                    'WKPROXY',
                    'XDB');
```

However, this will also filter legitimate non-system users whose names contain `SYS` or end in `SH`.  User `JOSH` will be lost.

Comment: Yeah, you probably are better of expanding the not in list explicitly with all names you don't want to select

Answer (score 2):

replace `or` with `AND` , I think it will start working.

However a better approach might be to have a flag indicating whether its a system user or not. A more sophosticated approach might be to have seperate table for rights that will have many to many relationship with User table.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
 select username from all_users where username not like '%SH%' 
        AND username not like '%SYS%'
    INTERSECT 
    select username from all_users where username not in ('ANONYMOUS',            
                            'DBSNMP',
                            'MGMT_VIEW',
                            'ORDPLUGINS',
                            'OUTLN',
                            'SI_INFORMATION_SCHEMA',
                            'WK_TEST',
                            'WKPROXY',
                            'XDB');
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work. You need to change the `OR` to an `AND` and change the `UNION` to and `INTERSECT`

Comment: @MikeyByCrikey: I have done changes. But Intersect doesn't work for some of the DBMS